combine different shapefile feature classes based on their names and geometry
I have a shapefile which contains various feature classes I'm able to read
I improved my code thanks to the suggestions of @Pieter
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely import box
from shapely.geometry.polygon import Polygon
from shapely.geometry.multipolygon import MultiPolygon

shapefile = "LAFIS.shp"
vect_data = gpd.read_file(shapefile)

vec_data.head()
vec_data['DESCR_ENG'].unique()
geometry_arr = (vec_data['geometry'])
descr_name_arr = (vec_data['DESCR_ENG'])
d = {
    "BW_name": descr_name_arr,
    "geometry": geometry_arr,
}
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(d, crs="EPSG:25832")
gdf

test_vector_data = gpd.GeoDataFrame(
    data={"DESCR_ENG": [
        "Cultivated Grassland,Alpe (without tare)",
        "Cultivated Grassland,Biennial cut meadow (tare 20%)/S28-1 Dry meadows and low bog meadows",
        "Cultivated Grassland,Biennial cut meadow (tare 20%)/S28-2 Species-rich mountain meadows",
        "Cultivated Grassland,Biennial cut meadow/S28-2 Species-rich mountain meadows",
        "Cultivated Grassland,Lawn special area (tare 20%)",
        "Cultivated Grassland,Lawn special area (tare 50%)",
        "Cultivated Grassland,Meadow (Half Sheared Tara 20%)",
        "Cultivated Grassland,Meadow (half-sheared)",
        "Cultivated Grassland,Meadow (half-sheared)/S28-1 poor meadows and fen meadows",
        "Cultivated Grassland,Mixed Alternate Meadow",
        "Cultivated Grassland,Pasture",
        "Cultivated Grassland,Pasture (rock 20%)",
        "Cultivated Grassland,Potential pasture (tare 20%)",
        "Fallow,Arable land fallow - EFA",
        "Forest Trees / SRF,Alpe (stocked 20%)",
        "Forest Trees / SRF,Alpe (stocked 50%)",
        "Forest Trees / SRF,Alpeggio (without tares)/S28-6 Wooded pastures",
        "Forest Trees / SRF,Biennial cut meadow (tare 20%)/S28-4 Meadows rich in tree species",
        "Forest Trees / SRF,Biennial cut meadow/S28-4 Species-rich meadows with trees",
        "Forest Trees / SRF,Biennial cut meadow/S28-5 Lush meadows with trees",
        "Forest Trees / SRF,Meadow special area (tare 20%)/S28-4 Meadows rich in wooded species",
        "Forest Trees / SRF,Meadow special area (tare 20%)/S28-5 Lush meadows with trees",
        "Forest Trees / SRF,Meadow special area (tare 50%)/S28-4 Meadows rich in wooded species",
        "Forest Trees / SRF,Meadow special area (tare 50%)/S28-5 Lush meadows with trees",
        "Forest Trees / SRF,Meadow special area/S28-4 Species-rich meadows with trees",
        "Forest Trees / SRF,Meadow special area/S28-5 Lush meadows with trees",
        "Forest Trees / SRF,Pasture (rock 20%)/S28-6 Wooded pastures",
        "Forest Trees / SRF,Pasture (rock 50%)/S28-6 Wooded pastures",
        "Forest Trees / SRF,Pasture (tare 20%)/S28-6 Wooded pastures",
        "Forest Trees / SRF,Pasture (tare 50%)/S28-6 Wooded pastures",
        "Forest Trees / SRF,Pasture (trees 20%)/S28-6 Wooded pastures",
        "Forest Trees / SRF,Pasture/S28-6 Wooded pastures",
        "Forest Trees / SRF,Stable meadow (tare 20%)/S28-4 Meadows rich in wooded species",
        "Forest Trees / SRF,Stable meadow (tare 20%)/S28-5 Lush meadows with trees",
        "Forest Trees / SRF,Stable meadow/S28-4 Species-rich meadows with trees",
        "Forest Trees / SRF,Stable meadow/S28-5 Lush meadows with trees",
        "Forest Trees / SRF,Willow (Tara 50%)",
        "Forest Trees / SRF,Willow (Tare 20%)",
        "Legumes,Alfalfa",
        "Legumes,Clover",
        "Maize,Corn",
        "Miscellaneous,Industrial Medicinal Plants",
        "Miscellaneous,Plant cultivation",
        "No Agriculture,Bosco/S28-8 Peat bogs and alders",
        "No Agriculture,Forest",
        "No Agriculture,Greenhouses",
        "No Agriculture,Hedges",
        "No Agriculture,Hedges/S28-9 Hedges",
        "No Agriculture,Infrastructures",
        "No Agriculture,Other Areas",
        "No Agriculture,Other crops/S28-3 Reedbeds",
        "No Agriculture,Other crops/S28-8 Peat and alder bogs",
        "No Agriculture,Water",
        "Orchards and Berries,Apple",
        "Orchards and Berries,Apricot",
        "Orchards and Berries,Astoni plants fruit",
        "Orchards and Berries,Berry fruit (without strawberry)",
        "Orchards and Berries,Biennial cut meadow (tare 20%)/S28-7 Chestnut groves and meadows with sparse fruit trees",
        "Orchards and Berries,Castagneto/S28-7 Chestnut groves and meadows with sparse fruit trees",
        "Orchards and Berries,Cherry",
        "Orchards and Berries,Chestnut",
        "Orchards and Berries,Currants",
        "Orchards and Berries,Meadow special area (tare 20%)/S28-7 Chestnut groves and meadows with sparse fruit trees",
        "Orchards and Berries,Meadow special area/S28-7 Chestnut groves and meadows with sparse fruit trees",
        "Orchards and Berries,Olive",
        "Orchards and Berries,Orchard being planted",
        "Orchards and Berries,Other fruit",
        "Orchards and Berries,Pear",
        "Orchards and Berries,Plums",
        "Orchards and Berries,Stable meadow (tare 20%)/S28-7 Chestnut groves and meadows with sparse fruit trees",
        "Orchards and Berries,Stable meadow/S28-7 Chestnut groves and meadows with sparse fruit trees",
        "Orchards and Berries,Strawberry",
        "Orchards and Berries,Table grapes",
        "Orchards and Berries,Vineyard under planting",
        "Orchards and Berries,Viticulture",
        "Other Cereals,Grain",
        "Permanent Grassland,Alpe (tare 70%)",
        "Permanent Grassland,Meadow (Permanent Meadow Tara 20%)",
        "Permanent Grassland,Meadow (permanent meadow)",
        "Permanent Grassland,Meadow (permanent meadow)/S28-1 poor meadows and fen meadows",
        "Permanent Grassland,Meadow (permanent meadow)/S28-2 species-rich mountain meadows",
        "Permanent Grassland,Meadow special area",
        "Permanent Grassland,Meadow special area (tare 20%)/S28-1 Dry meadows and low bog meadows",
        "Permanent Grassland,Meadow special area (tare 20%)/S28-2 Species-rich mountain meadows",
        "Permanent Grassland,Meadow special area (tare 50%)/S28-1 Dry meadows and low bog meadows",
        "Permanent Grassland,Meadow special area (tare 50%)/S28-2 Species-rich mountain meadows",
        "Permanent Grassland,Meadow special area/S28-1 poor meadows and fen meadows",
        "Permanent Grassland,Meadow special area/S28-2 species-rich mountain meadows",
        "Permanent Grassland,Potential pasture (50% tare)",
        "Permanent Grassland,Stable meadow (tare 20%)/S28-1 Dry meadows and meadows with low bog",
        "Permanent Grassland,Stable meadow (tare 20%)/S28-2 Species-rich mountain meadows",
        "Vegetables,Asparagus",
        "Vegetables,Cabbage",
        "Vegetables,Cauliflower",
        "Vegetables,Field vegetable cultivation",
        "Vegetables,Radish",
        "Vegetables,Salads",
    ]},
    geometry = [box(0, 0, 5, 5), box(5, 0, 10, 5), box(10, 0, 15, 5), box(15, 0, 20, 5)],
    crs=25832,
)
# Add new "Classes" column based on DESCR_ENG column
test_vector_data["Classes"] = None
test_vector_data.loc[test_vector_data["DESCR_ENG"].str.startswith("Cultivated"), "Classes"] = "Cultivated Grassland"
test_vector_data.loc[test_vector_data["DESCR_ENG"].str.startswith("Fallow"), "Classes"] = "Fallow"
test_vector_data.loc[test_vector_data["DESCR_ENG"].str.startswith("Forest"), "Classes"] = "Forest Trees"
test_vector_data.loc[test_vector_data["DESCR_ENG"].str.startswith("Legumes"), "Classes"] = "Legumes"
test_vector_data.loc[test_vector_data["DESCR_ENG"].str.startswith("Maize"), "Classes"] = "Maize"
test_vector_data.loc[test_vector_data["DESCR_ENG"].str.startswith("Miscellaneous"), "Classes"] = "Miscellaneous"
test_vector_data.loc[test_vector_data["DESCR_ENG"].str.startswith("No Agriculture"), "Classes"] = "No Agriculture"
test_vector_data.loc[test_vector_data["DESCR_ENG"].str.startswith("Orchards and Berries"), "Classes"] = "Orchards and Berries"
test_vector_data.loc[test_vector_data["DESCR_ENG"].str.startswith("Other Cereals"), "Classes"] = "Other Cereals"
test_vector_data.loc[test_vector_data["DESCR_ENG"].str.startswith("Permanent Grassland"), "Classes"] = "Permanent Grassland"
test_vector_data.loc[test_vector_data["DESCR_ENG"].str.startswith("Vegetables"), "Classes"] = "Vegetables"

# Print result
print(test_vector_data.head())


test_vector_data["geometry"] = [MultiPolygon([feature]) if isinstance(feature, Polygon) \
    else feature for feature in test_vector_data["geometry"]]


Each feature has its polygon in the geometry column.
I would like to collapse, for example, all the feature classes into one unique class listed in the first part of the name before the comma i.e. all those starting with "Cultivated Grassland" in Cultivated Grassland; "Forest Trees / SRF" in Forest Trees / SRF
The geometry of each feature should follow this criteria too to have one unique polygon for each grouped feature
Here you can find the file I'm using shapefile
Any suggestions?

The error: when creating a (Geo)DataFrame, all columns passed in should have the same number of rows, but the DESCR_ENG column now has 97 rows while the geometry column has 4 rows (the 4 "boxes"). But, I'm not sure why you create that GeoDataFrame. The result of read_file is already the GeoDataFrame you want to work with as far as I know? So I'd guess you would just want to add the "Classes" column to that GeoDataFrame instead of making another one?

@Pieter yes you are right. I want to add the "Classes" columns. Then I would proceed with the dissolve as you suggested.

For the different things you are trying to do:

You can use the standard pandas functionalities on a GeoDataFrame to add a column with new classes. After adding a new empty column you can update the values based on the existing "DESCR_ENG" column using loc.
Merging the geometries of all features with the same class is possible using dissolve.
Saving is possible using the geopandas to_file function.

Sample script:
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely import box

vec_data = gpd.read_file(r"C:\Temp\LAFIS\LAFIS_update.shp")
"""
# Test data if the shapefile is not available
vec_data = gpd.GeoDataFrame(
    data={"DESCR_ENG": [
        "Meadow (Half Sheed Tara 20%)",
        "Meadow (permanent meadow)",
        "Pasture (tare 20%)/S28-6 Wooded pastures",
        'Grain',
    ]},
    geometry=[box(0, 0, 5, 5), box(5, 0, 10, 5), box(10, 0, 15, 5), box(15, 0, 20, 5)],
    crs=31370,
)
"""

# Add new "Classes" column based on DESCR_ENG column
vec_data["Classes"] = None
vec_data.loc[vec_data["DESCR_ENG"].str.startswith("Meadow"), "Classes"] = "Agriculture"
vec_data.loc[vec_data["DESCR_ENG"].str.startswith("Pasture"), "Classes"] = "Cultivated"

vec_data_dissolved = vec_data.dissolve(by="Classes")

# Print result
print(vec_data.head())
print(vec_data_dissolved.head())

# Save to file
#vec_data.to_file(r"C:\Temp\LAFIS\LAFIS_update_dissolved.shp")


could you please explain the line:
geometry=[box(0, 0, 5, 5), box(5, 0, 10, 5), box(10, 0, 15, 5), box(15, 0, 20, 5)]
? In particular, what does the number mean in round brackets? Thanks in advance

That just some test data being created because I don't have your shapefile. You would use the GeoDataFrame returned from read_file. The box() function just creates a rectangular polygon.

how can I extract the corresponding geometry for each feature from my shp file and then join all together to create a unique geometry per classes?

read_file will load the geometries for each feature from the shapefile. After you added a column with the classes, you can use dissolve to merge all geometries per class...

I think I'm doing something wrong. I'm getting the following error when I create the vec_data.
I will edit my question to show my code and I will share the .shp file to explain better what I would like to achieve

I put the test data in comment instead of the read_file to avoid confusion + added the dissolve...

finally I got the shape file with the merged classes. The only thing that is still not working is that the dissolve function is converting from MULTIPOLYGON to POLIGON and this causes the error:
`from shapely.validation import make_valid
not_fully_within.geometry = not_fully_within.apply(lambda row: make_valid(row.geometry) if not row.geometry.is_valid else row.geometry, axis=1)
ValueError: Must pass array with one dimension only. `

Weird. dissolve should result in MultiPolygons instead of Polygons... so the other way around. Also no clue on geometries being polygons or multipolygons could lead to that error... probably there is something else wrong with the not_fully_within object. Best update the script so there is a minimal reproducable sample leading to the error...

perhaps I found a solution. These are the lines I added
from shapely.geometry.polygon import Polygon from shapely.geometry.multipolygon import MultiPolygon vector_data["geometry"] = [MultiPolygon([feature]) if isinstance(feature, Polygon) \     else feature for feature in vector_data["geometry"]]
I only got a warning now
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\geopandas\geodataframe.py:1819: SettingWithCopyWarning:
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

I updated my code in the question. I will do some more tests before considering the problem as solved

I did my tests and the file is correct now. Thanks for your support and collaboration.
